# Outlook Redemption multiple accounts

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

I have multiple email accounts in my outlook that I can read and send emails from. I can view these accounts from Redemption fine (and all their content), but what I also want is to be able to send emails from those accounts, not just the default. By default, Redemption sends emails from the default account. Can you please give me an example of how to send emails from different accounts that are loaded in Outlook (preferably in C#)?

Answer (score 0):

What are the secondary accounts? In case of Exchange delegate accounts, set the RDOMail.SentOnBehalfOfName property, other (POP3/SMTP), set the RDOMail.Account property.